# jQuery On Click function only works once

Tags: jquery, wordpress, onclick

I know there are many questions like this in stackoverflow but none of them seems to work for me. 
I think there is a logical error which prevents my onClick event from working multiple times. 
Also I want to pass the data-id attribute to target the right container by id. It does work, but only once. 
I am using this inside a wordpress page.
This is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('.change-aktiviert-btn').on('click', function(){
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        if($('#project-listing-container-'+id).hasClass("grey-bg")) {
            $('#project-listing-container-'+id).removeClass("grey-bg");
        } else {
            $('#project-listing-container-'+id).addClass("grey-bg");
        }
    })

})
```

relevant HTML would be:

```
<div id="project-listing-container-398" class="project-listing-container "></div>
    <button class="change-aktiviert-btn" data-id="398" onclick="changeStatus('Ja', 1, 398);" type="button" name="qr-link">
                    <div class="project-action-switch">
                        <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
                    </div>
        </button>
```

How can I fix it?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should provide the relevant HTML so we can debug.  However, you should maybe use .toggleClass instead.  That would simplify your code a lot.

Comment: FYI not what you've asked but you can just use `toggleClass()` instead of your `if`-`else`. `$('#project-listing-container-'+id).toggleClass("grey-bg");` http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: Thank you both, it simplified the code and works. But also only once tho:)

Comment: You should update your question to reflect that you're using AJAX to populate the button. As it stands its not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems to work multiple times for me. Demo below. There must be something else missing from your example. Although its not apparent in your question, I suspect that you are replacing the `.change-aktiviert-btn` element elsewhere in your code and thus loosing the event listener that was assigned to it. You can use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to avoid this.

```js
$(function(){

    $('body').on('click', '.change-aktiviert-btn', function(){//delegated
        console.log("click");
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        $('#project-listing-container-'+id).toggleClass("grey-bg");
    })

});

function changeStatus(a,b,c){
  //dunno what this is
  console.log(a,b,c);
};
```

```css
.grey-bg {
background:grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="project-listing-container-398" class="project-listing-container ">
I'm the listing container.
</div>
    <button class="change-aktiviert-btn" data-id="398" onclick="changeStatus('Ja', 1, 398);" type="button" name="qr-link">
                    <div class="project-action-switch">
                        <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
                    </div>
        </button>
```

Comment: The html Button is created by AJAX (after the first click, before it is printed by php). Could there be a conflict? Thats the changeStatus function. That works. And it also recreates the button with the correct class and data-id.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to add an event listener to an element that does not exist. Use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) in order to listen for events on elements that may not exist yet or will be replaced later. I've updated my demo to reflect this change.

Comment: Thanks very much. That was exactly what I was missing. Before I solved it by simply calling the function with html onClick and that worked too. But now I learned something new again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be missing information from your side regarding the `id`.

Please see working example here https://jsfiddle.net/0suxapvf/ with your code, where I added a attribute `data-id` for the click.

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="change-aktiviert-btn" data-id="1">Click here</a>

<div id="project-listing-container-1">
Project stuff here
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function($){

    $('.change-aktiviert-btn').on('click', function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        if($('#project-listing-container-'+id).hasClass("grey-bg")) {
            $('#project-listing-container-'+id).removeClass("grey-bg");
        } else {
            $('#project-listing-container-'+id).addClass("grey-bg");
        }
    })

})
```